# Javascript issue in Sencha touch Xtemplate

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

Extracting data from XML I want to preprocess one before sending it as a variable to template. A stackoverflow fellow pointed me to Ext.Xtemplate and that is close to do the job.

In each of my records I have a value "coordinates" of this pattern : 2.342556,48.873802,0.000000
3 items separated with comma. I need the first and the second.

So I decided to split but It doesn't work.

My attempt so far (trying to display only one value for testing purposes)

Code:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(        
        '<div>{name}<br>{[ values.coordinates.split(',')[1] ]}</div>'
             );
```

This echo nothing. 
If I display the [0] column of the array it displays the whole string, unsplited. This means that it didn't parse the comma.

If I split with something else it works (for example with an integer)

Code:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(        
'<div>{name}<br>{[ values.coordinates.split(6)[1] ]}</div>'
         );
```

I tried to split with the point ('.') but it throw an error ("unexpected string")

Maybe I should use a template member function but the example in the doc are not very clear for me.

Thanks for your help,

Julius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes or use double quotes like so:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(        
        '<div>{name}<br>{[ values.coordinates.split(\',\')[1] ]}</div>'
             );
```

Otherwise your call will be like this:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(        
        '<div>{name}<br>{[ values.coordinates.split(',   ')[1] ]}</div>'
             );
```

I.E. you pass 2 string parameters instead of 1.

A similar problem would be with this:

```
alert( 'o' 'hi there' );
```

Except this would throw a syntax error because there is no coincidential comma in there.

Comment: I did try to escape the single quotes without success. If I escape them nothing is displayed neither for the [0] column nor for the [1].

Comment: There are not double quotes in your first example